# PHP Include Trouble

Tags: php, include

I have been attempting to have includes as a part of my website for about 2 weeks now. Throughout multiple questions and long research I have figured out that php is the best way to go. I started with trying Server side includes in the html comment way, then I went to php and researched all of the different extensions needed for the include to work and so on. I had downloaded MAMP for the mac knowing that it would work with includes. I tried again and again with similar code with php and for whatever reason it did not work. Whether it was thenewboston on youtube or php's manual I had no success.

Finally, I came upon http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp .
I had saved their code into a folder and ran it on MAMP, it magically worked. I thought if I implemented this into my website it would work. Again, no success. So I'm asking you for help.

**The Code:**

**Footer: (footer.php)**

```
<?php echo'<div class ="footer">
<p>Contact Us! <br> @allwaterpolo</p>
<a href="#"><img src ="img/Facebook_Png_01.png" class="facebook" id="FaceBook Link" /> </a>
<a href="#"><img src ="img/Uiconstock-Socialmedia-Instagram.ico" class="instagram" id="Instagram Link" /> </a>
 <a href="#"><img src ="img/Twitter_Logo_Hd_Png_03.png" class="twitter" id="Twitter Link" /> </a>
<a href="#"><img src ="img/Youtube_icon.png" class="youtube" id="YouTube Link" /> </a>
<div class="aboutus">
<a href ="htmlfiles/aboutUs.php">About <br>Us</a>
</div>
<div class= copyright>
Copyright &copy; 2016<script>new Date().getFullYear()>2016&&document.write("-"+new Date().getFullYear());</script>, <br> All Water Polo. All rights reserved
</div>
</div> ';?>
```

**Header:(header.php)**

```
<?php echo'<div class ="header">
<h1>The Best Sport</h1>
<h1 class="sitetitle">AllWaterPolo</h1>
<img src ="img/51wmckj8p1l__sx300__1.png" class="wpball" alt="Water Polo Ball" />
<h2 class="homeScreenLink"> <a href ="index.html">Water Polo!</a></h2> </div>';?>
```

**Navigation Bar:(navbar.php)**

```
<?php echo'<div class="navBar">
    <ul>
    <li><a href ="htmlfiles/history.php">History
    </a></li>
    <li><a href ="htmlfiles/started.php"> Get Started</a></li>
    <li><a href ="htmlfiles/positions.php">Positions</a></li>
    <li><a href ="htmlfiles/rules.php">Rules</a></li>
    <li><a href ="htmlfiles/nationalleague.php">National League</a></li>
    <li> <a href ="htmlfiles/extras.php">Extras</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Videos</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Plays</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">TBA</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>';?>
```

**A Page In My Website: (aboutUs.php)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<title> Water Polo, The Best Sport</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<?php
include 'header.php' ;
?>
<?php
include 'navbar.php' ;
?>
<div class= "content">
</div>
<?php
include 'footer.php' ;
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

(I'm not allowed to post direct images yet)
[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0o6MM.png)

This time with the edition of the ../includes/header.php my page showed some hope. The only problem was that the includes did not access the css and image files and ended up with something like this: Sorry can't publish two pictures, but the new page had no css impact and looked like plain text.

Comment: What is the rrot directory ? Might need to indude it.

Comment: @sbswim can you show us your directory structure in your `htdocs` directory? It might gives us a clue on what's going on.

Comment: Just added it thanks! @LionelChan

Comment: what are you actually trying to do? What is the problem that you are having that you are trying to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MAMP, then I believe you put website files into a folder called `www`, am I right? Assume that is correct. You have a folder for this website called `waterpolo-site`, so you should be able to display the website by typing this into [Safari's address bar](http://www.macobserver.com/imgs/tmo_articles/20120924_safari601search5.jpg):

```
localhost/waterpolo-site
```

Safari's address bar should display: `http://waterpolo-site/index.html`. If this is not correct, please correct me.

(1) Usually, we would structure the website thus:

```
example.com
    - css
        styles.css
        bootstrap.min.css
    - js
        index.js
        jquery.min.js
        bootstrap.min.js
    - img
        logo.jpg
        pic1.jpg
        pic2.jpg
        another_pic.jpg
    - inc
        connect.inc.php
        head.inc.php
        header.inc.php
        footer.inc.php
        nav.inc.php
    index.php
    about.php
    history.php
    positions.php
```

If you structure the website folder structure as above, then all paths to files are straight-forward: `include "folder/file.ext"` or `<link href="folder/file.ext"`

(2) The file **head.inc.php** might look something like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'inc/connect.inc.php';
    //Any more PHP instructions here
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My Soccer Website</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="A description of my website goes here" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="soccer, football, hooligans, beer, beckham, stadium, scalpers" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png?v=2" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />

    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

(3) Notice that PHP code is only used to do PHP stuff - call functions, database lookups, session_start, etc. Once you close the PHP tag `?>` then HTML is output as if it was a `.html` file.

(4) The primary difference between a file that ends in `.php` versus one that ends in `.html` is that the PHP file can ***also*** process PHP commands. Both can process HTML exactly the same. There is really no need to ever use the file extension `.html`

(5) Notice the little trick on the `favicon`. If you update a file (css, js, etc) and you want visitors to use the new file instead of a previously fetched version stored in their browser's cache, then you can add a `?xxx=yyy` fake GET parameter and presto! they will download the updated version from your server. Next time they visit, though, they may use the version from cache unless you change that GET param again.

Comment: What is the connect.inc.php document used for? Also, does the start session command have to be included for the include to be processed? Thanks

Comment: `connect.inc.php` just contains the db connect commands, resulting in a variable that contains the db session. `start_session()` only needs to be on the page if you are using the `$_SESSION['varname']` server-side variable. Note that the `$_SESSION` variable has nothing to do with database sessions - it's a silly name for that variable, frankly, but they didn't ask me at the time.

Comment: Thank you so much after a month of trying its figured out!

Answer (score 0):

The PHP include statement is relative to the file it is accessed through...

EG:

If you access the site using index.php then the includes need to be...

`include("includes/footer.php");`

If you are accessing the pages directly, eg: http://domain.com/htmlfiles/aboutUs.php then the include needs to be...

`include("../includes/footer.php");`

Using the `../` path prefix is the equivalent of saying go up one level in the directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `include` using relative file path, PHP find the file by using current directory first, and then look for it in the include paths (include paths can be found via `phpinfo()`).

In your case, your `footer.php`, `navbar.php`, and `header.php` are all located in the includes directory, but your `aboutUs.php` located in the `htmlfiles` directory.

To fix it, you can do this:

**aboutUs.php**

```
include dirname(__DIR__) . '/includes/header.php';
```

*Experience talk: We don't usually do `include '../includes/header.php'` because this is evil. Although it looks fine from the first glance, if there is another file located in yet another directory try to include `aboutUs.php`, the relative path will change, and again your header will not be found. Doing `dirname(__DIR__)` is to ensure "I want the PHP to search this file relative to the directory of this current file, and not other files"*

---

The [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) statement is quite powerful, as it can be used for other fancy stuff as well, for example, include an array from another php file (for configurations), or even include the content from a URL. Do read it up :)